# Identification of class elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JavaScript since the last couple of days. I decided to write a script that adds points to the table, but I came across a class error.

How to add and relocate correctly to add a point always to the first field instead of assigned to it. I do not know where the mistake was - will you help?

```js
var ilosc = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");
var dodaj = document.getElementsByClassName("add");
var usun = document.getElementsByClassName("del");

for (z = 0; z < ilosc.length; z++) {

  for (i = 0; i <= dodaj.length; i++) {
    dodaj[i].onclick = function() {
      ilosc[z].value++;
    }

    for (u = 0; u < usun.length; u++) {
      usun[u].onclick = function() {
        ilosc[z].value--;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="inputs">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="add">Dodaj</button>
      <button class="del">Usuń</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="inputs">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="add">Dodaj</button>
      <button class="del">Usuń</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why nested  for  ??   you have 3 separated  input  .. no nested

Comment: Could you say something more about it?

Comment: I have  posted  an answer hope is useful